# Html Interpreter problems

Tags: c#, language-agnostic, logic

On the side since last year i've been writing an interpreter for HTML. I don't think HTML is a very nice language, and thought I might create an interpreter that translates my nice looking code into HTML for use on the web.

It works really well, and am using it on a little web app, but I'm having a problem parsing a particular line, and would appreciate any advice on how I could go about parsing it.

My code:

```
HmtlDocument {
    Page.Title: "Test webpage using JTHtml";
    Using[] {
        "../Assets/Stylesheets/default.css",
        "../Assets/Scripts/slidercordian",
        "../Assets/Scripts/jquery.1.4.1.js"
    };
HtmlBody {
    HtmlElement Divider(container) {
        HtmlElement Divider(Header) {
            HtmlElement Image(Logo, "../Assets/Images/logo.png");
            HtmlElement Menu(MainMenu, Horizontal, Ul, li) {
                li.Text: "Home", "index.html";
                li.Text: "About Us", "about.html";
                li.Text: "Services", "services.html";
                li.Text: "Contact Us", "contact.html";
                li.Text: "My Account", "../myaccount/default.html";
            }
        }
        HtmlElement Divider(MainContent) {
            HtmlElement Heading(Heading, 1) {
                Heading.Text: "Welcome!";
            }
            HtmlElement Text(Text) {
                Text.Text: "Welcome to my new website written purely in jthtml";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See, the problem I am having is with the following line:

```
li.Text: "[value]", [resource]";
```

The old way I had it was to write it like this:

```
li.Text("[value]", "[resource]");
```

However, that doesn't quite stay true to the rest of the syntax, which is why I would like to keep it like this:

```
li.Text: "[value]", "[resource]";
```

But I'm just not sure how I would parse that line. I'm getting stuck because of the first closing quote and the following comma, space and second opening quote. I can't seem to figure out the right logic for it.

Any help at all is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Html Interpreter problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504895/html-interpreter-problems)

Comment: That link no longer exists. S/O created two copies of this question when I clicked "Ask Answer". There is only this one now. No longer a dupe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line: li.Text: "[value]", [resource]"; is missing an opening quote.

Are you missing an opening quote or is the parser suppose to understand it without the opening quote?

Comment: Awwwwww that animal was sooo cute. A little tiny cute animal just popped up and pointed to the tick after I upvoted you

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the line, you can easily use a regex like

```
li\.Text:\s*"([^"]*)"\s*,\s*"([^"]*)"\s*;
```

But that seems like something you could figure out by yourself. Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question?